# "No module named six" error after "sudo pip install six"

Tags: python, pip, six

when I run python code, debug said `No module named six`. And I go to terminal to install. I got:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):  six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

Then I run python again, still got `No module named six`.
How to deal with it?

Comment: Do you have multiple Python installations?

Comment: I have 2.6 and 2.7. But I don't think 2.6 working. I am going to delete it right now.

Comment: try `sudo chmod -R o+rX /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python` - sometimes using `sudo pip install` leaves the installed packages only readable by root.

Comment: delete 2.6. And try @mata comments , but still not working.

Comment: never mind. I use " python setup.py install" to install it